# $\bigcap_{t>T}\{|B_t| >0\}$ is not $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable.

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

**Edited**

I am working on the following problem

> Let $\{B_t\}$ is Brownian motion. Here, $\tau = \sup\{t\in [0,5]: B_t=0\}$. Show that  $$\{\tau \leq T\}=\bigcap_{t\in(T,5]}\{|B_t|>0  \}\not\in \mathcal{F}_T$$
>   where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is canonical sigma algebra of $B_t$ i.e., is generated by $B_t$.

I think it is true because the intersection is about 'future event' which should not be determined by observing the current event at time $T$. But I cannot see why it should not be there.  Is there any good reason that the intersection is not  $\mathcal{F}_T-$measurable?

This problem has been arisen from proving that last zero random time is not a stopping time.

Comment: Note that the set $\{t \geq 0; B_t(\omega)=0\}$ is unbounded, and therefore the intersection from your first display is nothing but the empty set. Hence, it is in $\mathcal{F}_T$.

Comment: @saz Then it doesn't seems right because your results says that last zero random time $$\tau=\sup\{ t\in [0,5] : B_t=0   \}$$ is a stopping time which is well know that it is not.

Comment: @saz  Note that for $T=5$, $\{\tau\leq T\}=\Omega\in \mathcal{F}_T$.

Comment: @saz Also, note for $T\in (0,5)$,  $$\{\tau \leq T\}=\{|B_t|>0, \hspace{2mm}\forall t>T  \}=\bigcap_{t>T}\{|B_t|>0\}$$

Comment: No, that's not correct. It should read $$\{\tau \leq T\} = \{|B_t| >0 \forall t \in (T,5]\} = \bigcap_{t \in (T,5]} \{|B_t|>0\}.$$

Comment: @saz I thought that is not but, now, it seems right! I am sorry about it. Do you know by any chance if the intersection in your equation is in $\mathcal{F}_T$?

Comment: @saz I edited the question corresponding to our conversation!